# How to install PHP using asdf

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo, libpq, asdf-vm

I am trying to install PHP using asdf on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS without success. While installing, it generates many errors regarding missing packages in the main installation like the absence of re2c, bison, libcurl, etc... I succeeded in install all these packages but now when I try to install PHP through asdf I am getting the following error:

```
checking for PQprepare in -lpq... no
configure: error: Unable to build the PDO PostgreSQL driver: a newer libpq is required
```

Anyone can help me to fix this problem?

PS.: I have PHP 7.4.3 installed in my system. I installed it through apt command.

Comment: what do you mean by asdf??

Comment: It is a version manager that allows installing of different versions of certain programming languages or other tools and switch between versions. Here is the project's official page https://asdf-vm.com/#/